# the word "whole" in one sentence

Tags: word-usage, phrase-request

*I have read some excerpts of the book but to tell the truth I am not interested in reading it whole.*

*I have read some excerpts of the book but to tell the truth I am not interested in reading the whole of it.*

Are both sentences grammatically OK and synonymous? Namely I have in mind the use of the word "whole".

Answer (score 1):

I would use:

> I am not interested in reading **the whole thing**.

especially in a negative context. Another option might be:

> I am not interested in reading **all of it**.

in this case it is implied that you might read part of it.

There are probably others. I would not use your wording in context.